# matching multiline text with pyparsing

Tags: python, text-mining, pyparsing

I am using pyparsing api to extract the content for a given input text which have, usually, the following structure.

```
  Key1 : Value1 \n
  Key2 : Value2 \n
   .   :   .    \n
   .   :   .    \n
   .   :   .    \n
  Keyn :   .    \n
```

In some cases, the value for a given key can be long and thus it is written in more than one line.

```
 Key_k  :   Value_k value_k value_k
          value_k value_k value_k
```

When I have some key with a long value such the above example I have always only the content in the first line.

This is BNF defined for my pyparsing:

```
keyName = Word(pp.alphanums + '_')
unitDef = Suppress('(') + Word(alphanums + '^*/-._') + Suppress(')')
paramValueDef = SkipTo('*' | lineEnd)

paramDef = keyName('name') + pp.Optional(unitDef)('unit') + pp.Suppress(":" + pp.empty) + paramValueDef('value')
```

I have a good results when the key and value are written in the same line.

Any help will be welcome and thank you in advance.

Comment: Imagine all these keys and values were written on a single line with no line breaks. How would you tell the difference between a key and a value?

Comment: Also, how tolerant/intolerant do you want to be about where people put or don't put spaces, especially around those all-important `':'`s?

Comment: Thank you for your smart answer. The delimiter is the novel line that contains the ":" sympbol. 
Regarding your second question, do you mean only spaces or also back on a novel line.

Answer (score 1):

With Paul on board offering comments I know that my answer is bound to be suboptimal. But I love attempting problems that are open to solution with pyparsing.

One way of doing this is to say that a 'value' is something that doesn't have white spaces and a colon following it whilst a 'key' is. Therefore, I define a syntactic element called `key_ending`.

I want keys and values to be grouped in the result; I therefore use `Group`.

```
>>> import pyparsing as pp
>>> key_name = pp.Word(pp.alphanums+'_')
>>> key_ending = pp.ZeroOrMore(' ') + ':' 
>>> key = key_name + key_ending
>>> value = pp.Word(pp.alphanums) + pp.NotAny(key_ending)
>>> values = pp.OneOrMore(value)
>>> param = pp.Group(key + values)
>>> param_stream = pp.OneOrMore(param)
>>> lines = '''\
... key1 : value1 
... key2 : value1 value2 
... key3: value1
... key4 : value2
... value3 value4
... '''
```

This line demonstrates that the parsing has been successful.

```
>>> param_stream.parseString(lines)
([(['key1', ':', 'value1'], {}), (['key2', ':', 'value1', 'value2'], {}), (['key3', ':', 'value1'], {}), (['key4', ':', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4'], {})], {})
```

I do the parsing again, capturing it this time so that I can display the individual bits of it.

```
>>> r = param_stream.parseString(lines)
>>> for param in r.asList():
...     param[0], param[2:]
...     
('key1', ['value1'])
('key2', ['value1', 'value2'])
('key3', ['value1'])
('key4', ['value2', 'value3', 'value4'])
```

After doing this it occurred to me that I could have taken the tack of using pyparsing's FollowedBy, and there is the built-in for finding key-value pairs.

Comment: Should work just as well if you remove the `pp.ZeroOrMore(' ')` from `key_ending`.

Comment: @PaulMcG: Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much Bill Bell. I have tried your code but I have nothing as a result !!! I have even tried with another text example but I have always an empty result.

Comment: You're welcome. Would you give us one of the examples you've tried? You can post it on pastebin.com, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I have any result when I tried with the following example:

```
From: Blabla bhlkf <Blabla.bhlkf@atghg.tele2.com>
Sent: 2014-01-22 14:21:31
To: "support@atghg.com" <support@atghg.com>
Subject: Blablablabla bla bla Subject
Case request:                           STL Cas Hours (JKLM, KJH 1 24x7 EPLi
Loc)
Request Type:                           Support (HTL)
Product:                                TGHLKI HS+ / BLOS V. 9.9.x.x
Product Instance State:                 In Service
DSLAM address:                  HGJLKM
Problem Description:                    All usershoud be in nkowns
                               that the first line should be also extracted
Ticket Priority:                                3 = Very import request
Contact Name:                           Blabla
Contact phone:                          +0187 87652 99883 
Alternate phone:                        +012 7890 877343 1 9009 35
Tele2UTA Ticket ID:                     HGFDL5666
Service Agreement:                      7543864
Contact Company:                        FAX2
xlfswott01> users -l | grep 001.14.06
616804042  001.14.060/0001 001:14:060/ 2044K/ 252K ATM 0.0.0.0      
1:14:60-0.100-T-066048   0:07:31    0:00:00
616804043  001.14.060/0001 001:14:060/ 2044K/ 252K ATM 0.0.0.0      
1:14:60-8.35-T-066048    0:07:32    0:00:00
616804044  001.14.060/0001 001:14:060/ 2044K/ 252K ATM 0.0.0.0      
1:14:60-8.40-T-066048    0:07:32    0:00:00
616804054  001.14.064/0001 001:14:064/ 2044K/ 252K ATM 0.0.0.0      
1:14:64-0.100-T-066050   0:07:20    0:00:00
616804055  001.14.064/0001 001:14:064/ 2044K/ 252K ATM 0.0.0.0      
1:14:64-8.35-T-066050    0:07:20    0:00:00
616804056  001.14.064/0001 001:14:064/ 2044K/ 252K ATM 0.0.0.0      
1:14:64-8.40-T-066050    0:07:21    0:00:00
616804057  001.14.065/0001 001:14:065/ 2044K/ 252K ATM 0.0.0.0      
1:14:65-0.100-T-067398   0:07:22    0:00:00
616804058  001.14.065/0001 001:14:065/ 2044K/ 252K ATM 0.0.0.0      
1:14:65-8.35-T-067398    0:07:25    0:00:00
616804059  001.14.065/0001 001:14:065/ 2044K/ 252K ATM 0.0.0.0      
1:14:65-8.40-T-067398    0:07:26    0:00:00
<end user list>  3053 active user(s)
<grep> Found 9 line(s) matching search criteria
xlfswott01> users -l | grep 001.14.05
616804031  001.14.054/0001 001:14:054/ 6997K/ 903K ATM 0.0.0.0      
1:14:54-0.100-T-004048   0:08:14    0:00:00
616804032  001.14.054/0001 001:14:054/ 6997K/ 903K ATM 0.0.0.0      
1:14:54-8.35-T-004048    0:08:15    0:00:00
616804033  001.14.054/0001 001:14:054/ 6997K/ 903K ATM 0.0.0.0      
1:14:54-8.40-T-004048    0:08:16    0:00:00616804034  001.14.055/0001
001:14:055/ 7997K/ 903K ATM 0.0.0.0         1:14:55-0.100-T-065997   0:08:17   
0:00:00
616804035  001.14.055/0001 001:14:055/ 7997K/ 903K ATM 0.0.0.0       
1:14:55-8.35-T-065997    0:08:17    0:00:00
616804036  001.14.055/0001 001:14:055/ 7997K/ 903K ATM 0.0.0.0      
1:14:55-8.40-T-065997    0:08:20    0:00:00
616804037  001.14.057/0001 001:14:057/ 2044K/ 252K ATM 0.0.0.0      
1:14:57-0.100-T-071069   0:08:20    0:00:00
616804038  001.14.057/0001 001:14:057/ 2044K/ 252K ATM 0.0.0.0      
1:14:57-8.35-T-071069    0:08:22    0:00:00
616804039  001.14.057/0001 001:14:057/ 2044K/ 252K ATM 0.0.0.0      
1:14:57-8.40-T-071069    0:08:23    0:00:00
616804040  001.14.059/0001 001:14:059/ 2044K/ 252K ATM 0.0.0.0      
1:14:59-0.100-T-155435   0:08:23    0:00:00
616804041  001.14.059/0001 001:14:059/ 2044K/ 252K ATM 0.0.0.0      
1:14:59-8.40-T-155435    0:08:24    0:00:00
616804048  001.14.050/0001 001:14:050/ 2044K/ 252K ATM 0.0.0.0      
1:14:50-0.100-T-064163   0:08:09    0:00:00
616804049  001.14.050/0001 001:14:050/ 2044K/ 252K ATM 0.0.0.0      
1:14:50-8.35-T-064163    0:08:08    0:00:00
616804050  001.14.050/0001 001:14:050/ 2044K/ 252K ATM 0.0.0.0      
1:14:50-8.40-T-064163    0:08:10    0:00:00
616804051  001.14.051/0001 001:14:051/   13M/1047K ATM 0.0.0.0      
1:14:51-0.100-T-080123   0:08:10    0:00:00
616804052  001.14.051/0001 001:14:051/   13M/1047K ATM 0.0.0.0      
1:14:51-8.35-T-080123    0:08:10    0:00:00
616804053  001.14.051/0001 001:14:051/   13M/1047K ATM 0.0.0.0      
1:14:51-8.40-T-080123    0:08:13    0:00:00
<end user list>  3050 active user(s)
mit HFDSKJKJR LIKLSS
BLAB HGFDO
COMPANY Telecom
DESEARCH DEVELOPEMENT Network Operation Center (NOC)
Donau-City-Strasse 11, 1220 Wien
service@atgljkfyh.com
******** WICHTIGER HINWEIS ********
balblablablbalbalnbabTele2bmlablablalablaba.
blablablablaba.
******** IMPORTANT NOTICE ********
blablablbalbablabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb.
lablablbalablblb.
```

It is also noteworthy to mention that I am interested to extract only the informations that match with the structure described in my first post..Meaning the data having the form:

```
Key : value
key_n: value_n1...
       valume_mn
```